# How to save and pass username and password when redirect in external link in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

i make a login page , after login must redirect to external link , how to save user and pass in login ? i need after click in button login my users logged in external website

i use

```
"axios": "^0.18.0","react": "^16.8.5",
"react-dom": "^16.8.5",
"react-router": "^5.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
```

```
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


        const bodyParameters = {
            params: {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
                appType: this.state.appType
            }
        }


        axios.get(
            'http://localhost:8080/test/api',
            bodyParameters,

            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.hasError !== true) {
                const token = localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)



                axios.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token');

                window.location = 'http://localhost:8082/test'
                return response.data

            } else {
             console.log('error')
            }


        }).catch((error) => {

        });
```

Comment: This is better delegated to the server. It's too unsafe to manage this in the client. But, one way to do it would be with localStorage (assuming that it's in the same tab) another would be with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local storage -

```
       axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost:4000/login',
        data: {
            user_email: formData.user_email.value,
            user_password: formData.user_password.value,
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res && !res.data.error) {
            localStorage.setItem('sessionID', res.data.data.sessionID);
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('sessionEmail', res.data.data.sessionEmail);
            localStorage.setItem('notify', JSON.stringify({msg: res.data.message, type: 'success'}));
            this.props.history.push("/testlist");
        } else if (res.data.error) {
            localStorage.setItem('notify', JSON.stringify({msg: res.data.message, type: 'error'}));
        }else if ( !res.data.error) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token', res.data.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('notify', JSON.stringify({msg: res.data.message, type: 'error'}));
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('notify', JSON.stringify({msg: res.data.message, type: 'error'}));
        }
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        localStorage.setItem('notify', JSON.stringify({msg: '500 api error', type: 'error'}));
    });
}
```

Comment: how to redirect? use window.location ?

Comment: this.props.history.push use for a window.location